# Security in Unity

Tags: unity, software-engineering

I have a public int variable in my game for number of coins. It's public because it must be accessed in other scripts and scenes (for when you want to buy levels, character,etc). I want to use anti-cheat toolkit and as I'm new to unity I don't know whether it's safe.

Comment: Can anyone provide a bit of clarification on this question's downvotes considering the apparent helpfulness of the answer?

Comment: @Natalo77 IMHO, it's only helpful to new programmers. I would say the "legitimate" reasons for the downvotes come from "not enough research" aspect. Most likely, some though "dude you're so newb" and downvoted for that.

Comment: @amin007 TBH, if you ask this question, it reflects that you still have a lot of stuff to learn, and so I suggest you focus on releasing a single player game with no micro-transaction as your first experience. This makes cheating completely futile, and you can focus on learning the engine and game development in general.

Comment: @Vaillancourt fair point - it just seems a little unfair considering the answer was so good

Comment: @Natalo77 Yes, and on that note, the answer has a great positive score ;)

Answer (score 3):

Public or private doesn't matter to cheaters.

Access control modifiers like that are just a fiction, a polite agreement between coders and the IDE to pretend that private members are inaccessible, to make the program easier to reason about.

It's trivial to work around them as a coder if you want to do so, and for hackers they're all just bytes in memory, as easy to read or change as any others.

When thinking about security in a client-side application like a game, it's important to remember: "Your code is in the hands of the enemy"

No amount of obfuscation or added complexity in your game client code will stop a determined hacker. They can decompile your code and remove or neutralize whatever extra checks you've put in place, or snoop the information out of system memory.

The *only* way to be truly secure is to put the sensitive information on a server that you or a trusted party controls, behind a strict set of rules on what transactions can be done on it. (eg. If it's entitlements to in-app purchase content, validate that they're only ever unlocked when spending the required amount of currency or a valid & unused voucher code)

Everything else just gives the hackers a slightly higher hurdle to vault. If your game gets popular, trust that a skilled hacker *will* vault it, and turn their exploit into a script that even unskilled hackers can use to accomplish the same feat.